# Open to Discuss: How would you describe <website / product> in one word?

Tags: user-expectation, ux-field, usability-study, surveys

As UX people know, these type of questions are really good for capturing perceptions of a website / product. So you let your service users to enter their own words or choose one or more from a list.

Therefore, as result of this question you will get a lot of data that have to be saved somewhere and it is not meaningful if there are no effective analysis technique.

The Question is: is there any ready tool or framework to use in order to capture those data and analyze it so that we can get benefits from it (for instance a sentiment analysis)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR: Yes! There is!!**

I am unfamiliar with sentiment analyses (apart from a quick Wikipedia lookup!), but from an academic perspective, this is touching on UX research using qualitative and quantitative methods. If I had to work with this situation, I would have used the word association (which is essentially a quantitative survey) as a gateway technique to meeting the critical users: the unhappy users that you may lose to your competition.

Let's say someone describes the website/product as '**good**' - well -- *why* is it good? Maybe you leave it at that. How about '**bad**'?

Their reason for choosing<sup>1</sup> or writing *that* particular word is definitely something you need to know about as a UX advocate - and qualitative research methods (such as an interview or focus group) can be employed to probe these users further.

Using *just* the survey is fine for doing a 'temperature check' of how the users experience the website/product. However, to really get the benefits, I would recommend digging deeper. In this approach, your tools would be the research methods (survey, interview), and your framework would be the research methodologies (qualitative, quantitative).

<sup>1</sup> *Having a list of preselected words makes the analysis easier as there is less interpretation to do - but on the flip side, you may 'box' people in, and lead them to pick certain words. Also keep culture in mind if this is a situation that involves multiple nationalities!*

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [google forms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/) as it will enable you to easily create this kind of survey and get exploitable data. You will then be able to export them and get a more visual result with tools likes [Word Cloud Generator](https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/).
[image]

**For an offline version**; to avoid the necessity of inserting all the data by yourself, you may want to consider alternatives that measure users satisfaction like the [System Usability Scale (SUS)](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/system-usability-scale.html) or a simpler version the [Net Promoter](https://www.netpromoter.com/know/). Exploiting the data will then require doing some statistics.

For further reading: http://measuringux.com